# Track iOS App’s Mobile data and WiFi usage

Tags: ios, swift, vpn, ios-app-extension, http-tunneling

I am working on a mini project to track iOS app’s mobile data and WiFi data.  I saw some apps doing that through VPN , but I had no luck with NSExtentions.

Any reference is appreciated. I would like to collect device level data which includes all apps . Similar to the stats available in

> [Settings-> Mobile data](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201299)

Apart from native iOS client , other apps  [listed here](https://www.imore.com/best-apps-track-your-cellular-data-usage) also achieve this. I know its possible through VPN but i could not find any development documents related to it. Is there any other method apart from VPN?

Comment: If it's only for YOUR application, you can use `URLProtocol`.. to check what your app is using.. how many bytes sent and how many received for all requests..

Comment: @Brandon Thanks for your response , i will check that . I would like to collect device level data which includes all apps . Similar to the stats available in Settings-> Mobile data